# css code not working in mvc apart from background image

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017

some css code aren't working with my mvc website

I have created a Layout which linked to the css file. A view page is using that Layout. When i load the page, It know how to get the background image but some simple code doesn't work. I also found out adding the headers into my text class from css worked but other class don't. Tried to use the css file directly without the layout, result in the same way. Please let me know if more information is needed. i appreciate any kind of help, Thank you

CSS Code aren't working

```css
h2{
 font-size: 35px
}

nav {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

working css code

```css
body {
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    background-image: url('/Images/pawwallpaper.jpg')
}

.text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    color: #FC5A37;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

view that is using the Layout

```html
@model ToysListViewModel

    <h1>@Model.CurrentCategory</h1>
    @foreach (var toy in Model.Toys)
    {
    <nav> <!--change this to <div class="text"> worked -->
        <center>
            <img src="@toy.ImageUrl" alt="" height="420" width="420" />
            <h2>@toy.Name</h2>
            <h3>@toy.Price.ToString("c")</h3>
            <h4>@toy.Category.CategoryName</h4>
            <p>@toy.ShortDescription</p>
        </center>
    </nav>

    }
```

The layout

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap.4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="~/Content/site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=dive-width, initail-scale=1" />
    <title>Tigerpaw</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the element inspector in your browser on an element you believe should be styled by your rules? It will tell you if any other CSS is overriding your settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try adding id?

```
<div id="test">
<h1>@Model.CurrentCategory</h1>
@foreach (var toy in Model.Toys)
{
<nav> <!--change this to <div class="text"> worked -->
    <center>
        <img src="@toy.ImageUrl" alt="" height="420" width="420" />
        <h2>@toy.Name</h2>
        <h3>@toy.Price.ToString("c")</h3>
        <h4>@toy.Category.CategoryName</h4>
        <p>@toy.ShortDescription</p>
    </center>
</nav>

}
</div>

#test h2{
 font-size: 35px
}

#test nav {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

If you don't want any new values ​​to be corrupted, you should use !important.

Answer (score 0):

your css are not useful because of using bootstrap library but if you want to use them without adding a class or id to your attributes you need to add !important to your css codes like below :

```
h2
{
    font-size: 35px !important;
}
```